# Executar URL de sistema diariamente através do agendador de tarefas do Windows

Tags: windows

Gostaria de agendar uma tarefa no Agendador de Tarefas do Windows. Consiste em, diariamente, em determinado horário, abrir o navegador e executar determinada URL (que executará algumas tarefas {inserts, updates..) de um software).

Já sei como agendar a tarefa. Preciso somente do script .bat que fará a ação de abrir o navegador e executar a URL. Alguém que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do ponto que já sabe como agendar a tarefa, então crie um arquivo em lote (*.bat) com a seguinte linha e agende sua execução:

```
start https://br.stackoverflow.com
```

Isso fará o seu navegador padrão abrir a URL informada.

Outra alternativa é agendar uma tarefa solicitando a execução do navegador desejado e passando a URL como argumento.

[image: Tarefa agendada para ser executada no Firefox, mesmo que o navegador padrão seja outro.]

Neste caso a tarefa está agendada para ser executada no Firefox, mesmo que o navegador padrão seja outro.